# Why is my nav bar showing behind my table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a button that creates a table and a button that when clicked shows a nav bar. I'm using css, html, and js. 
Currently, when the nav bar is clicked the options show underneath the table already made, instead of over it - like it should. 
I'm not sure why this is happening. I have tried index-z and that hasn't worked. If anyone has a solution to offer that would be appreciated. 
Here is the code I'm having trouble with and the HTML:

```
//**HTML**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='NoteTaker.css'>
    <script src= 'NoteTaker.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p class='date'></p>
<div contenteditable='true' class='notes'></div>
<div class = 'clearsPage buttonStyle'>Clear</div>
<div class = 'insertsGrid buttonStyle'>Grid</div>
<div class = 'checkableBullets buttonStyle'>Check</div>
<div class = 'insertImage buttonStyle'>Image</div>
<div class = 'addSketch buttonStyle'>Sketch</div>
<div class = 'textModify buttonStyle'>Aa</div>
</body>
</html>

//**CSS**
    th, td, tr {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .drop-down {
        width: 10%;
        height:1%;
        border:1px solid black;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .dropDownContent  {
        display: none;
    }
    .dropDownContent1 {
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:white;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 80%;
    }

//**Javascript**
    const insertsGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('insertsGrid');
    insertsGrid[0].addEventListener('mousedown', createGrid);
        function createGrid (){
            document.execCommand('insertHTML' , true, '<div class=drop-down>
<div class =dropDownContent><p>Add Row</p><p class=addColumn>Add Column</p></div></div><table><tr><td>Head1</td><td>Head2</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>');
        const dropMenu =    document.getElementsByClassName('drop-down');
        const dropDownContent = document.getElementsByClassName('dropDownContent');
        const addColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('addColumn');
        dropMenu[0].addEventListener('mousedown' , tog);

    function tog (){
        dropDownContent[0].classList.toggle('dropDownContent1');
        }
    }
```

Comment: HTML Attribute values must be surrounded by quotes (preferably doubles " )

Comment: Post your HTML here as well

Comment: @RandyCasburn attributes are not required to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index AND a positioning to the element:

```
.dropDownContent1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80%;

    z-index: 15;
    position: relative;
}
```

Z-index only works on **positioned** elements.

Comment: Please don't set your z-index to 999. Use scale, 1-10, for 'standard' emelents, 11-20 for element that you now needs to be on top - like navbars, footers etc., and 21-30 for modals, fullscreens elems and so on. If you put 999 then another developer will have a very hard time quesing if he needs to use 99 or 199? or 999 or 9999 or 99999...

Comment: @AdamOrlov thank you for your suggestion, I have edited my answer.